# Proving that the infinite self-composition of $f(x)= \frac{x}{2} + 1$ is 2 for any $x$ value

Tags: alternative-proof, continued-fractions

I already solved this problem but I look for more creative and different approaches. Here is my own solution:

Let's define $f_n$ as composition of the function $f$ with itself $n$ times: $f \circ f \circ ... \circ f.$
Here our $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + 1$ and we want to prove that the limit $f_n(x)$ converges to $2$ as $n$ goes to infinity. My solution was using continued fractions to represent infinite composition.

If we say $y = \frac{\frac{...}{2} + 1}{2} + 1$ and multiply each side with $2$ then subtract $2$ from both sides, we will have $2y - 2 = \frac{...}{2} + 1$ which happens to be $y$ again.

$$2y - 2 = y$$
$$y = 2$$
QED.

So what would be a good alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you compute  a few terms of the sequence you can guess what $f_n(x)$ looks like.

Prove by induction that $f_n(x)=\frac x {2^{n}}+\frac  1{2^{n-1}}+\cdots +\frac 1 2 +1$. The limit is $1+\frac  1 2+\frac  1 {2^{2}}+\cdots =2$.